# Apache kafka about replica and partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to follow

https://medium.com/@iet.vijay/kafka-multi-brokers-multi-consumers-and-message-ordering-b61ad7841875

to create multiple brokers and consumer.

I am able to produce message and consume the same.

when i try to describe the topic the below is the output which I got.

[image]

Can some one explain me about the partitions and leader and replicas here in above image.

Comment: Suggest that you get a copy of the book https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/

Answer (score 1):

All producer and consumer requests are sent to the leader broker, which is elected by the Kafka Controller.

Replicas are the non-leader broker. Replicas can be in or out of sync with the leader (ISR = "in sync replica")

The numbers that are shown are each of the `broker.id` values from the broker properties, which default to increment from 0 if not set

More details at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication

Worth pointing out that running multiple brokers on a single host is less than ideal; you still have a single point of failure and you're causing unnecessary duplicate writes on single hard drive for each replica